# Is this Drop7 game 'recoverable'?

Tags: drop7

I have been a little addicted to Drop7 on iPhone recently. A few days ago I got to the following situation:

[image: Drop7 layout]

Is this situation salvageable? Each column is blocked by 1-discs or 2-discs, and the columns are above 2 rows high, so as I see it, those discs cannot be removed, nor can the grey discs below be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way out of that situation that won't result in the end game.

You can drop the 6 on either of the 7's. That will trigger the 7, that will drop and trigger the 6 and then trigger the 3's.

Unfortunately, that will leave you with all the 2's and 1's and no way out from there. You can trigger the lone 2 on the left, but the combination of 1's and 2's leaves everything underneath inaccessible to trigger. You will obviously have chances to get more points, but there will be no way to get completely out of that situation.

Comment: Thanks, I pretty much figured that was the case. I actually did what you mentioned when I played to remove the 7337 at the top, but found no way to save the game.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat As far as I know there is no method to save a game and reload unfortunately.

Comment: By "save" I actually meant salvage/recover. However, with regards to saving progress, the game will continue where you left off when you reopen the app. But AFAIK you can't save progress and start a different game.

Comment: Sorry, totally misread that 'save' out of context, makes sense.